# Summing of time complexities into one single representation

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis

### Background

**I have some code, I have written.**

The time complexity for building the Graph with `Nodes` + `connections` is calculated to be $O(N^2)$, even though in the `constructor` there is first, one $O(N^2)$ for creating the graph, and the second nested-`for` loop is for building the edges between nodes i.e. connections. Again, the constructor has a nested-`for` loop for initializing the `row`, `column`, `n * m`;

The `BFS` has $O(V + E)$ time complexity. Finally, in the AI itself, there are two nested `for` loops, one nested for loop, and then below that one, is a separate nested `for` loop. The calculation here regardless of the fact that there are two separated nested `for` loops within the same code, $O(N^2)$.

**The sum:** $$O(N^2) + O(V + E) + O(N^2) \Rightarrow O(N^2) + O(N) + O(N^2) \rightarrow O(N^2)$$

**Rule:**

$$N = V + E$$

---

**My question:**

*Is this how its done? Is this correct?*

**EDIT:** All for-loops start from $N - 1$.

Comment: You should probably work with $|V|$ and $|E|$ instead of $N$. In that way, it is clearer to what exactly you refer. However, usually, $|V|=N$, so $|E|\le N^2$.

Comment: @nirshahar, good point. *Toda raba!* What else can you share. Is this wrongly calculated.

Comment: You might not want to combine the analysis of the methods (functions) you have, since each one might be called a different amount of times. For example, a constructor will be called only once - so even if it took much longer than $O(N^2)$, it would have probably been fine. However, if you call the "AI function" many times, then you might not want to tolerate a high complexity.

Comment: Interesting point. For the remaining time of the program, the call happens to the BFS to find next closest path, in a Quoridor game. Remove edges which the two separated nested for loops are used for detecting if a wall is placed. In the AI part of the code. The overall $O(N^2)$ program time complexity becomes like that, when we calculate it.

Comment: @nirshahar. is the calculation result that we reached completely wrong?